# plural or singular in this sentence:

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which should I write:

> - Successive rules are separated by **semicolons**
> - Successive rules are separated by **a semicolon**
> - Successive rules are separated by **semicolon**

In fact after each rule there is a semicolon. Here I don't know *successive* rules points to two rules separated by a semicolon or multiple successive rules separated by semicolons? or maybe it doesn't matter!

What about *The rules are separated by semicolons*? I think in this case I certainly can't say *The rules are separated with a semicolon*. right?

Comment: All of those sentences convey the same meaning and will be interpreted the same way.  The first example contains a slight ambiguity in that it is possible for successive rules to be separated by multiple semicolons but it will not be understood that way. The third sounds more like the answer to "How are successive rules separated? (although the first and second are both acceptable as well).

Comment: You can't just say "by semicolon" - *semicolon* is a count noun, so it has to be "a semicolon" or "semicolons".

Comment: @stangdon I don't know who cast the close vote, but I enhanced my question further to express my main problems.

Comment: If you're looking for advice in a specific domain, you could write "In a list of rules the semicolon is used as the *delimiter*."

Comment: And you CAN say "delimited by semicolon".  The article is not necessary. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22separated%20by%20comma%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @TRomano strange, they say *semicolon* needs an article, but you use it without an article, what is the difference of "separated" and "delimited" which makes such a difference!

Comment: **Delimiter** is a term of trade. Programmers understand it to mean the character which is used to demarcate items in a list.  **separated** is a more general term.  We would say "An empty seat separated them in the crowded theater" but not "An empty seat delimited them...."  You can say separated by semicolon or delimited by semicolon. The article is not required in either case (but can be used).

Comment: Compare: "These slices of bread are not all the same. Some are thinner, some are thicker. Obviously they have been *cut by knife* not by a bread-slicing machine."

Comment: Judging from the streaks, the paint was applied by brush not by spray applicator.

Comment: @TRomano interesting, and in fact, such comparisons made me suspected to "separated by semicolon", However, I still didn't get a complete rule to differentiate it with "cut by knife". it seem how much common or idiomatic the combination is has a role.

Comment: @TRomano about delimited and separated I also should add, comma-separated is a well known term in Programming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: You're not referring to a particular brush or even to an instance of class brush, but to a mode of paint application. It is similar to zero-determiner role. *The prayer must be recited by priest or deacon.*

Comment: I don't dispute that comma-separated exists alongside comma-delimited. I am all too familiar with CSV files. But "delimited" is a term-of-trade and separated has broader meaning.

Comment: @TRomano you mean a general noun which is absent from the existing context? for example because "semicolons" are visible in a sample ruelset, zero-article is not applicable? but for brush it is.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. But I said the article was *not* necessary (separated by semicolon). Why would you think from my last half-dozen comments that I meant "zero-article is *not* applicable"?

Comment: @TRomano right! I misunderstood by this sentence *And you CAN say "delimited by semicolon". The article is not necessary*, However, I didn't notice the google link. I thought you say if I use "delimited" then article is not necessary! and concluded with "separated" it is. Sorry!

Comment: @TRomano lol, if you review my recent comments, you can see this confusion, as I was seeking for to know why it is applicable for "delimited" but not for "separated"!

Comment: @Ahmad: And if you review my comments you will find "You can say separated by semicolon or delimited by semicolon. The article is not required in either case (but can be used)."

Comment: @TRomano The article you cite says exactly the opposite of what you are claiming. Every example given uses either a plural, "commas", or a singular with an article, "a comma".

Comment: @Jay: I didn't cite an article, I cited a search. The search results (not the top article) are full of attestations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **Successive rules are separated by a semicolon.**

- 1st case: Says that two rules are separated by multiple semicolons.

  Correct result: `Rule1;;Rule2;;;;Rule3`
- 2nd case: Says that two rules are separated by a single semicolon.

  Correct result: `Rule1;Rule2;Rule3;Rule4`
- 3rd case: Same as 2nd case. But there the article 'a' is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As stangdon says in a comment:

> You can't just say "by semicolon" - semicolon is a count noun, so it
>   has to be "a semicolon" or "semicolons".

Out of the remaining options, my preference is for the first ("Successive rules are separated by semicolons") but the second is also grammatical ("Successive rules are separated by a semicolon"). I don't think there's any overwhelming logical basis for one or the other.

Here is some evidence from Google Books that I think shows that people use plural nouns like this alongside "successive rules" (bolding added):

> ***Composites*, are rules** that are created by merging at least two
>   **successive rules** of a parse tree of a solution. (["Online Modeling the Novice-Expert Shift in Programming Skills on a Rule-Schema-Case Partial Order](https://books.google.com/books?id=nfysCfUVs3UC&pg=PA74&dq=%22successive%20rules%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF6srvuKPPAhVM04MKHUECCVMQ6AEISzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22successive%20rules%22&f=false)," by Claus Möbus, Olaf Schröder and Heinz-Jürgen Thole, in *Cognition and Computer Programming,* edited by Karl F. Wender, Franz Schmalhofer, and Heinz-Dieter Böcker)

Note that this sentence starts with "Composites are rules..." and not "A composite is a rule...".

> Error estimates for these rules are usually computed using
>   **differences from successive rules**... (*[Computation of Multivariate Normal and t Probabilities](https://books.google.com/books?id=ogmGaOJ-4DMC&pg=PA53&dq=%22successive%20rules%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwm_etuaPPAhXo6IMKHbnnBWU4FBDoAQgiMAE#v=onepage&q=%22successive%20rules%22&f=false),* by Alan Genz and Frank
>   Bretz)

Note that this says "differences from successive rules" and not "the difference from successive rules."

Comment: Thanks but according to the comments of  @tromano under the question, the third option is also possible.